# Suppose $C, D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If $C$ is compact and $D$ is closed, is the following assertion true?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm looking at the following math problem:

> If $C$ is compact and $D$ is closed, then there are points $c \in C$
>   and $d \in D$ such that $d(C, D) = |c - d|.$

Here is an (unofficial) solution to the problem:

> We have that $d:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R:\ x\mapsto d(x,D)$ is
>   comtinuous.  Now, $C$ is compact, so there is a $c\in C$ and a real
>   number $d'$ such that $d(c,D)=d'$ and $(c,d')$ is a minimum for $d$ on
>   $C$.
>
> So by definition of $d$, there is a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq  D$ such
>   that
>
> $\tag1 d(c,x_n)=|c-x_n|<d'+1/n,$
>
> $(1)$ implies that $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence of numbers in $D,$ so
>   that $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. That is
>   $x_{n_k}\to d''\in D$ (because $D$ is closed).
>
> We conclude that $d(c,x_{n_k})\to d(c,d'')$ (because $d$ is
>   continuous), and that (from $(1)$), $d(c,d'')\le d'$. But, equality
>   must hold because $d'$ is a minimum, so in fact, $d(c,d'')=d'$.

But, I don't understand why

> Now, $C$ is compact, so there is a $c\in C$ and a real number $d'$
>   such that $d(c,D)=d'$ and $(c,d')$ is a minimum for $d$ on $C$.

is true. Can someone please explain? Is this solution correct?

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set always attains its maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1):

$d(C,D)$ is the minimum value of $d(x,D)$ as $x$ ranges over $C$. In other words it is the minimum of the the continuous function $x \to d(x,D)$ on the compact set $C$. Every continuous function on a compact set attains its minimum value. [ To prove that $x \to d(x,D)$ is continuous you can use triangle inequlaity to verify that $|d(x,D)-d(x',D)|\leq d(x,x')$].